# how to generate google map Api key from http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html.

Tags: android

> How to generate google map Api key from
>      http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

I am not familiar with the link you posted but have used the guide from vogella with success.

Answer (score 0):

```
 keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore USERNAME_HOME/.android/debug.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android
```

Where `USERNAME_HOME` is Your home directory, for example in Windows `C:\Users\USERNAME\` or Linux `/home/USERNAME/`

EDIT:

`keytool.exe` program is in Your Java JDK directory `bin` folder, for example `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_VERSION\bin`